# Number of solutions of $3\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x+\sqrt{3} \sin x+\cos x+1=\sqrt{3}\sin x\cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find Number of solutions of

> $$3\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x+\sqrt{3} \sin x+\cos x+1=\sqrt{3}\sin x\cos x$$ in $\left[0 \:\: 10\pi\right]$

My Try:

The given equation is

$$2+2\sin^2 x+2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (2x)$$ $\implies$

$$3+2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (2x)+\cos (2x)$$

Any idea here?

Comment: Are you sure it is $3\sin(x)^2$ and not $2\sin(x)^2$ ? The problem is actually much more interesting if the leading coefficient is a $2$.

Comment: If you are ever going to try to apply trig rules to simplify a problem like this, then it is usually easier just to do an Euler substitution $$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}2$$ $$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{ix}}{2i}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rewrite the equation as $\left(\sqrt 3 \sin x - \cos x \right)^2+ \left(1+ \sqrt 3 \sin x \right) \left(1+\cos x\right) = 0$

Let $a=1+ \sqrt 3 \sin x$ and $b=1+\cos x$

Then the equation is $(a-b)^2+ab = 0 \Rightarrow a^2-ab+b^2 =0$

But $a^2 -ab+b^2 = 0 \iff a=0,b=0 $ which is not possible.

Hence the equation has no solutions.

Comment: Hari shankar sir thats a great technique thanks a ton

Comment: Thank you for the kind words!

Answer (score 1):

Expand out the difference (left side - right side) as

$$ F(x) = 4-2\,  \cos^2 \left( x \right)  +\sqrt {3}\sin \left( 
x \right) +\cos \left( x \right) -\sqrt {3}\sin \left( x \right) \cos
 \left( x \right) 
$$

If $\sin(x) = s$, $\cos(x) = \pm \sqrt{1-s^2}$, and
$$ F(x) = 2 + 2 s^2 + \sqrt{3} s \pm (1-\sqrt{3} s) \sqrt{1-s^2}$$

In order for that to be $0$, we'd need

$$ \sqrt{1-s^2} =  \mp \frac{2 s^2 + \sqrt{3} s + 2}{1-\sqrt{3} s} $$

and thus $$1 - s^2 = \dfrac{(2s^2 + \sqrt{3} s + 2)^2}{(1-\sqrt{3} s)^2}$$
so that
$$ 7\,{s}^{4}+2\,\sqrt {3}{s}^{3}+6\,\sqrt {3}s+9\,{s}^{2}+3 = 0$$

This quartic has positive discriminant ($209088$), so its roots are either all real or all non-real.  In this case they turn out to be all non-real.

Comment: But Graphing tool showing that above quartic has two repeated real roots $s=-0.517$

Comment: Not a very good graphing tool, or poorly used.  There is a minimum at approximately $-0.5168241819$, but the value there is approximately
$0.054184098$.

Comment: ok fine i used desmos

Answer (score 1):

Let $c = \cos(x)$ and $s = \sin(x)$, solve for $c$:

$$3s^2 + c^2 + \sqrt 3 s + c + 1 = \sqrt 3 cs$$
$$c^2 + (1 - \sqrt 3 s)c + 3s^2 + \sqrt 3 s + 1 = 0$$
$$c = \frac{\sqrt 3 s - 1 \pm \sqrt{ (1 - \sqrt 3 s)^2 - 4(3s^2 + \sqrt 3 s + 1)}}{2}$$

Normally here you'd check the range on the discriminate, but the discriminate is a perfect square, so:

$$c = \frac{\sqrt 3 s - 1 \pm \sqrt{ -9s^2 - 6\sqrt 3 s - 3}}{2}$$
$$c = \frac{\sqrt 3 s - 1 \pm i\sqrt{(3s + \sqrt 3)^2}}{2}$$
$$c = \frac{\sqrt 3 s - 1 \pm i|3s + \sqrt 3|}{2}$$

So if $s$ is real then $c$ is complex, so no solutions.